# How to save Admin FTP password

Tags: password, ftp

Every time I attempt to upload a plugin or theme, I am asked for the FTP password.  Is there a way to save this within Wordpress, or do I have to enter it every time?  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can save this information on your wp-config.php file:

```
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp_host');
define('FTP_USER', 'ftp_username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'ftp_password');
```

[More info](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#wordpress-upgrade-constants) (WordPress Developer Resources)

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do this. chown -R apache:apache /var/www/wordpress*

Saving this data as shown above into wp-config creates a bigger vulnerability because anyone with CLI access can then see the password for your ftp server as that user, and do anything they can do on the file system (unless chrooted, say).